# Viewing uploaded .PDF or .DOC as pictures without converting

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Recently, I am working on a feature which the user could upload files like .pdf or .doc and then viewing them as pics on the web page. I am wondering is there a way that I can do that without actually converting them to .jpg or .png by a third party software on the server?  Is it possible to implement this feature only us js,jquery and django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about .doc you would need to go and convert that into PDF. You can show PDFs by using created by Mozilla

[pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/)

Comment: sure its just a js library like anyother (e.g. jquery)